# Python threading.Timer sometimes Stop or Pause or Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer, python-multithreading

My code is summarized like this.

```
import threading
import time

def checkMinute(num):
    print('check ' + str(num))
    print(str(num) + ' work start')
    # other python code....
    print(str(num) + ' work end')
    startTimer(num)

def startTimer(num):
    t = threading.Timer(10, checkMinute, args=(num,))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    
if __name__== '__main__':
    startTimer(1)
    startTimer(2)
    startTimer(3)
    time.sleep(1000)
```

It have to work continue before keyInturrepted.

But sometimes, I don't know how to say this but, it stop or pause or freeze.

For example, console log like this

```
# 10am in real time. program is start
2021-04-21 10:00:00 : check 1   
2021-04-21 10:00:00 : 1 work start
2021-04-21 10:00:00 : check 2   
2021-04-21 10:00:00 : 2 work start
2021-04-21 10:00:00 : check 3   
2021-04-21 10:00:00 : 3 work start
2021-04-21 10:00:13 : 1 work end
2021-04-21 10:00:20 : 2 work end
2021-04-21 10:00:21 : 3 work end
# I want continue it
# but sometimes
2021-04-21 17:10:21 : 3 work end
# Next, 'check 1' and '1 work start' have to progress
# But the real time is 9pm, but no progress has been made since the program stopped at 5pm.
# When I input enter on command window, It work again with no error
```

Why is this happening?
How can I fix it?

python version is 3.6.